# Objects falling around an axle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Say you have an object connected to an axle that is on the ground. Call the object's mass $m$, the object's height $h$, and the object's width to be $w$. What would be the final acceleration (not angular acceleration) of the top of the object when it hits the ground if it has an initial velocity of 0 and begins perpendicular to the ground? Does the acceleration change and is it dependent on the mass of the object? I unfortunately was not able to find any useful results, as everything I found is either unrelated or talks about angular acceleration. I am trying to calculate the force of a hammer falling around an axle and need the acceleration.

[image: A diagram depicting the scenario]

Comment: Since the center of mass of the object travels in a circular arc, the problem is intrinsically angular. However, you can still find the force with which the top of the object strikes the ground; it is an impulse problem, however, you will have to know the details of time over which the impulse occurs. You cannot assume that the stop is instantaneous without getting that the force is infinite; in real life bodies deform and it takes a definite amount of time for them to come to a stop, not to mention that the interaction of the bodies might not be simple over the entire time of interaction.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus Thank you so much! Is there a way I could get a reasonable approximation? An error of below 10% is completely fine for what I'm doing.

Comment: I think an estimate would be easily possible, however, I am unable to do so because I have no idea what the real life details would be...Indeed, how long will it take the hammer to come to a stop?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus As you can probably tell, I am not incredibly knowledgeable about physics, and I don't exactly know what you mean by coming to a stop; are you talking about how the object will bounce slightly when it hits the material? If my interpretation is correct (correct me if I am wrong), I think in the scenario of a hammer (which is usually made of high-carbon steel) hitting plastic (I should have specified that the ground is made of plastic) it should be adequate to only take into account the first collision as the others will be negligible given the non-bounciness of the materials.

Comment: I realize now that I was thinking of collisions as instantaneous when they are not. Do you think one could figure out the force being applied given the dimensions and mass of the hammer by getting a rough approximation for the amount of time the two are in contact, or by circumventing that obstacle using a different strategy to solve the problem?

Comment: Well, you could use the work energy theorem, for example, calculate the rotational kinetic energy, do the experiment and measure the depth of the dent of the plastic to get a distance over which the force does work to stop the hammer and then set the two equal and solve for the force.  That might provide a reasonable answer. But, who knows, maybe plastic will partially restore itself so that the measured dent is not the real distance?

Comment: Do you really need force which requires knowledge of the impact time which is difficult and involves guesswork. If for example you wanted to know the impact of the collision and how much damage is done, it easy enough to compute the final linear velocity, kinetic energy and momentum.

Comment: This question was closed because it was tagged  homework, but is it really homework? It looks more like a personal project and the diagram does not seem to be from a text book. Perhaps you rephrase the question to explain what you are trying to achieve and why?